# C# char pointer, Calling C++ dll functions and passing parameters

Tags: c#, c, dll

I want to call a C function from C#. C function is inside a dll. The function I want to call is declared as follows:

```
int raxml_main(int argc, char*[] argv);
```

The problem is I am new to C# and I don not know how to convert `string[] args` to `char*[] argv`. Is it possible? Any idea?

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21(v=VS.90).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I combined two answers and it worked.
Here is the solution:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("RaxmlDLL.dll", EntryPoint="raxml_main")]
public static extern  int raxml_main(int argc, string[] argv) ;
```

Answer (score 4):

try using below:

```
public static extern int raxml_main(int count, string[] argv);
```

You need to decorate with appropriate `DllImport`.

Sometimes `string` has to be declared as `StringBuilder` but I doubt it is necessary here since **you** are sending the string.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to write the DllImport part?

Comment: It can be as simple as `[DllImport("mylibrary.dll")]` but all other  parameters depend on how it is defined and on the library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tools like the [PInvoke Interop Assistant](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120) to generate the signatures you need. In your case it is:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("yours.dll", EntryPoint="raxml_main")]
public static extern  int raxml_main(int argc, System.IntPtr[] argv) ;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the string to a byte array, but you have to make sure that the encoding in the raxml_main function is compatible (ascii encoding may be more approperiate).

This is just some code I found online.

```
 // C# to convert a string to a byte array.
 public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string str)
 {
     System.Text.UTF8Encoding  encoding=new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
     return encoding.GetBytes(str);
 }
```